# How to fetch the values present in a url from a webview and append it to another url and load in android?

Tags: android, regex, webview

Consider the url: www.xyz.com/buy/thankyou/handlers/display.html?ie=UTF8&asins=B00F0G8K&orderId=404-35644-70307&purchaseId=404-2849-9658 as 1st url. The 2nd url is : sndbx.abc.com/mob#?path=confirmOrder&oid= &pid= &asins= . Here the values of the orderid(multiple), purchaseId and asins from the first url should be filled here in the 2nd url ie, 2nd url should be
 sndbx.abc.com/mob#?path=confirmOrder&asins=B00F8K&oid=40444-7037&pid=4089-958.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replaceAll("[&][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,}[=]","")` will replace all the keys from 2nd url which dont have values..

`URL_1.split("?")[1]` will give u all the key- values pair and hence..

```
URL_2= URL_2.replaceAll("[&][a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]{1,}[=]","").concat(URL_1.split("?")[1] );
```

will do the needful.
hope this helps 
cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you may use simple splitter of URL, might be creates as some static helper or whatever. for example:

```
String url1 =..., url2=...;
String[] url1splitted = url1.split("&");
for(String pair:url1splitted){
    if(pair.contains("=") && pair.length()>=3 && getCount(pair, '=')=1){
        String param = pair.split("=")[0];
        String value = pair.split("=")[1];
        // add to HashMap, format another url or whatever...
    }
}

//getCount method
private int getCount(String pair, Char lookingFor){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<pair.length(); i++)
        if( pair.charAt(i) == lookingFor )
            counter++;
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: they are dynamic urls, i'll get the url using webView.getUrl(). later on I need to perform this action.

Comment: and what is the problem? just fetch this url and then perform copying params to another url, or fetch both and then copy... you might keep these params in `HashMap` (or any other `Collection`) like comment says and future use